# How can I get the list of names used in a formatting string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

Given a formatting string:

```
x = "hello %(foo)s  there %(bar)s"
```

Is there a way to get the names of the formatting variables?  (Without directly parsing them myself).

Using a Regex wouldn't be too tough but I was wondering if there was a more direct way to get these.

Comment: It's [very easy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter) if you can switch to the new style formatting.

Comment: not really an option, unfortunately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `dict` subclass with overridden `__missing__` method and from there you can collect all the missing format variables:

```
class StringFormatVarsCollector(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.format_vars = []

    def __missing__(self, k):
        self.format_vars.append(k)
...         
def get_format_vars(s):
    d = StringFormatVarsCollector()     
    s % d                    
    return d.format_vars
... 
>>> get_format_vars("hello %(foo)s  there %(bar)s")
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: FWIW, this is the method I decided to use.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to parse the string, you can use this little function:

```
def find_format_vars(string):
    vars= {}
    while True:
        try:
            string%vars
            break
        except KeyError as e:
            vars[e.message]= ''
    return vars.keys()
```

`>>> print find_format_vars("hello %(foo)s  there %(bar)s")
['foo', 'bar']`

Answer (score 3):

The format fields are only significant to the `%` operator, not the string itself.  So, there is no attribute like `str.__format_fields__` which you can access in order to get the field names.

I'd say that using Regex is actually the correct approach in this case.  You can easily use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract the names:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "hello %(foo)s  there %(bar)s"
>>> re.findall('(?<!%)%\(([^)]+)\)[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]', x)
['foo', 'bar']
>>>
```

Below is an explanation of the pattern:

```
(?<!%)             # Negated look-behind to make sure that we do not match %% 
%                  # Matches %
\(                 # Matches (
(                  # Starts a capture group
[^)]+              # Matches one or more characters that are not )
)                  # Closes the capture group
\)                 # Matches )
[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]  # Matches one of the characters in the square brackets
```

Comment: I'd also look for one of the valid formatting characters after the closing parenthesis; `[diouxXeEfFgGcrs]` should do.

Comment: There, I think I ironed out all the kinks. :)

Comment: What about `"hello %%%(foo)"`?

Answer (score 3):

New style string formatting has this ability.

```
from string import Formatter

f = Formatter()
x = "hello {foo}s  there {bar}s"
parsed = f.parse(x)
```

The results of parsed will be an iterable of tuples with this format:
(literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion)

So it's simple enough to pull out the field_name section of the tuple:

```
field_names = [tup[1] for tup in parsed]
```

Here's the documentation if you would like more in-depth information
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter

Single list-comprehension version:

```
[tup[1] for tup in "hello {foo}s  there {bar}s"._formatter_parser()]
```

Comment: BTW in Python 2 it is as simple as: `parsed = x._formatter_parse`.